# Code optimization - Automatic click

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

guys.

I am using the following code on tampermonkey / violentmonkey to automatically approve entries in my database.

The code it self works fine but since I need to use in several two tabs and the entries are high so I'm wondering if there a way to make it faster.

```
window.onload=function(){

setInterval(autoBypass,1500); };

function autoBypass(){
if(document.getElementsByClassName("error").length>0){
document.getElementsByClassName("bypass")[0].click();
}
else{setInterval(autoAprove,500);}
}

function autoAprove(){
 if(document.getElementsByClassName("aprove").length>0){
 document.getElementsByClassName("aprove")[0].click();
}
}
```

I'm using 1.5s to give time to the page to load but sometimes - especially when I'm using Opera browser - it gets stuck on a loop and I have to close the tab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs `autoBypass` every 1500ms. Every 1500ms, `autoBypass` tells `autoAprove` to run every 500ms. After one minute, `autoAprove` has run 1740 times, and it only gets worse from there. More and more of the browser's time is spent running your code, leaving it unable to respond to input.

One or both of those timers should be `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much.
I used setTimeout on both timers and this allowed me to use 1ms without canceling a click with another one, greatly improving performance.
Opera seems to be working fine too. Thanks again man!